# Overlapping of buttons Ionic Framework

Tags: ionic-framework

I am new to developing in ionic framework. i have created a page with image buttons using the grid layout. but the overlap each other.

this is my code:

```
  <center>
  <br>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col ">
  <a class="button button-clear" href="#/app/deals">
  <img src="img/bagnew.jpg" width="70%">
  </a>
  </div>
 <div class="col">
<a class="button button-clear" href="#/app/search">
<img src="img/search.jpg" width="70%">
</a>
</div>
</div>
</center>
<center>
<div class="row">
<div class="col ">
<a class="button button-clear" href="#/app/favourites">
<img src="img/star.jpg" width="80%" >
</a>
</div>
<div class="col">
<a class="button button-clear" href="#/app/news">
<img src="img/paper.jpg" width="70%" >
</a>
</div>
</div> 
</center>
```

the star and paper images buttons overlap half of the bagnew and search image buttons.

please help. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ionic has built-in css classes to use while loading images, you can try out the class `item-image` to the `div` that renders the image. Modified code

1. to include `col-50` for two column grid and
2. `item-image` to render image within a column.
3. removed `width` specified for `img` tag

The entire changed code as follows:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col col-50 item-image ">
  <a class="button button-clear" href="#/app/deals">
   <img src="img/bagnew.jpg">
  </a>
 </div>
 <div class="col col-50 item-image">
  <a class="button button-clear" href="#/app/search">
   <img src="img/search.jpg">
  </a>
 </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col col-50 item-image ">
    <a class="button button-clear" href="#/app/favourites">
     <img src="img/star.jpg">
    </a>
   </div>
   <div class="col col-50 item-image">
    <a class="button button-clear" href="#/app/news">
      <img src="img/paper.jpg">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found out that the clera button in ionic framework have a fixed height. so they have been causing the overlapping. once i have changed that max-height to none in css file the images aligned properly. Thanks :)